# Regression and Neural network

Tags: neural-network, linear-regression, logistic-regression

I am taking Andrew NG's video lecture. Suddely I wondered if regression method is widely used or not. Is Neural network more often used? I just wondered if Andrew is explaining about regression as an introductory material. I want to hear from the person using machine learning in the field.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't related to any coding problem, so it probably may fit better in other StackExchange communities like [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). This said, let's try to bring some insight in the linear classifier vs. neural network topic. Quoting the [DeepLearningBook](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/), page 168:

> One way to understand feedforward networks is to begin with linear models
> and consider how to overcome their limitations. Linear models, such as logistic regression and linear regression, are appealing because they may be fit efficiently and reliably, either in closed form or with convex optimization. Linear models also have the obvious defect that the model capacity is limited to linear functions, so the model cannot understand the interaction between any two input variables. To extend linear models to represent nonlinear functions of x, we can apply the linear model not to x itself but to a transformed input φ(x), where φ is a nonlinear transformation.

I highly recommend to read that section (the book is available online as HTML). But summarizing, there are two main approaches to extend linear models:

1. Map the input to a very generic, high-dimensional space, and perform the linear classification there (the approach of [kernel machines](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html#pf2d) like the SVM that you'll see in the course).
2. Let your model learn the mapping! **this is the approach of the neural networks**: it gives up convexity, but is much more flexible and performs better (at least nowadays).

**Practical considerations:** The advantage of approach 1. is that it doesn't require much configuration to work reasonably well on any generic problem. Note that in most applications, currently the 2nd approach (basically deep learning) performs better, but requires a lot of [domain specific knowledge](https://sciencedryad.wordpress.com/2014/01/25/grad-student-descent/) to achieve that performance, and sometimes there isn't enough time and/or resources for that.

**Technical considerations:** Note that training a linear model via closed form *requires at least `O(n^2)` operations, for n the size of your training set*. And running inference can be `O(n)`. On the other hand, neural networks trained with Stochastic Gradient Descent are "arguably in `O(1)`".

And to back up this affirmations, from the DLB, chapter 5:

> - Prior to the advent of deep learning, the main way to learn nonlinear models was to use the kernel trick in combination with a linear model. Many kernel learning algorithms require constructing an m×m matrix `G_i,j = k (x(i), x(j))`. Constructing this matrix has computational cost O(m^2), which is clearly undesirable for datasets with billions of examples.
> - A major drawback to kernel machines is that the cost of evaluating the decision function is linear in the number of training examples, because the i-th example contributes a term `α_i k(x , x(i))` to the decision function. Support vector machines are able to mitigate this by learning an α vector that contains mostly zeros.
> - One can argue that the asymptotic cost of training a model with SGD is `O(1)` as a function of `m` (training set size).

So summarizing, linear models (mostly using kernel trick) are still a reasonable *off-the-shelf* choice for generic tasks that don't require a state of the art performance or much configuration. But if you have enough data, GPU power and the possibility of tuning the model properly, deep neural networks will provide better results in most problems with better asymptotic complexity. The drawback is that you give up most of the interpretability, your assumptions on the problem become more difficult to express explicitly and your setup in general becomes highly empirical.

This is at least the general trend that most sources (like the DLB I cited) seem to observe. Hope this helps!

Cheers,
Andres

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, Regression and Neural Network should be use both. We do not know which model is working well, so we need to build model as many as possible. In addition, after building models, we can compare or asses our model using given assessment statistic.